# Angular component test TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Tags: angular, angularjs, unit-testing, components

I am new to angular. And trying to write some unit test. Keep getting undefined (reading 'value')
//this is my component class (Thank You in advance)

```js
export class inputComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
   public flag!: boolean;
   public params: any;

   agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
     const fieldName = params.colDef?.field;
     let name: string = fieldName!
     this.flag = params.data[name];
     this.param = params;
   }

   refresh(params: ICellRendererParams) {
     this.params = params;
     return true;
   }
```

here is my test

```js
it('should agInit and refersh', () => {
 component.agInt(<ICellRendererParams>{ data: {"test": true}, colDef: {fiedl: "test"} })
 component.refresh(<ICellRendererParams>{ data: {"test": true}, colDef: {fiedl: "test"} })
 expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

and I get:

> TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Comment: Is this your whole test ? How did you initialize component ? Edit : actually in your test you've got a typo "fiedl" instead of "field"